# How to count a specific tags in xml file?

Tags: xml, extendscript, adobe-indesign

XML:

```
<chapter>
<openr><title><num aid:pstyle="_CN">1</num></title></openr>
<media.block id="fig001"><media type="image"/><caption aid:pstyle="Caption"><num>FIG. 1.1&#x2002;</num><para><txt>some text</txt></para></caption></media.block>
<txt>some</txt>
<media.block id="fig002"><media type="image"/><caption aid:pstyle="Caption"><num>FIG. 1.2&#x2002;</num><para><txt>some text</txt></para></caption></media.block>
</chapter>
```

I need to extract the count of `<media.block`(to get the no.of figures in a document) and the content of `<num aid:pstyle="_CN">1</num>`(here ans=1).

I don't know how to access XML element using extendscript. Atleast a hint would be more than enough

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but: decide if you need to treat this as a xml file or not. Simply using a text search feature can be much faster than running this through a XML library.

Comment: but, shall I know which would be an efficient way for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a lot of ways. One is as simple as using the built-in XML object in Javascript:

```
xmlFile = File ('/test.xml');
xmlFile.open();
var myString = xmlFile.read();
xmlFile.close();

myXml = new XML ();
myXml = XML(myString);

media_block = myXml.xpath("//media.block");

alert (media_block.length());
```